# ¿Cómo puedo implementar SweetAlert en Django?

Tags: javascript, html, django, sweetalert2

He estado intentando implementar las alertas de sweet alert en mi código y no me quieren funcionar. Estoy siguiendo este [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w-f0yzfCLvo&list=PLxm9hnvxnn-j5ZDOgQS63UIBxQytPdCG7&index=28) y tengo todo igual a el.

Este es el script que tengo en mi archivo base:

```
<script src=" {% static 'lib/sweetalert2-9.10.0/sweetalert2.all.min.js' %} "></script>
```

Y ya tengo todo dentro de mis archivos estáticos. Este es el código que tengo en el html donde quiero implementar la alerta:

```
<script>
  
  {% if form.errors %}
    var errors = '';
    {% for field in form %}

      {% for error in field.errors %}
        <li>
          errors += '{{error}}\n';
        </li>
      {% endfor %}
                    
    {% endfor %}

    Swal.fire({
    title: 'Error!',
    text: errors,
    icon: 'error',
    })
  {% endif %}

</script>
```

He comparado con el archivo del video y tengo todo igual, no sé qué puedo hacer para que me funcione. Sería de mucha ayuda si alguno me dijera cómo puedo implementar fácilmente esas alertas en mi proyecto de Django.

Comment: Lo mejor que te puedo recomendar es que revises la devtools (<kbd>F12</kbd>) y veas si el archivo `sweetalert2.all.min.js` en efecto está siendo importado. También asegúrate que es `<script>` tag que usas para importar sweetalert venga antes que el `<script>` donde haces uso de las template tags de django.

Answer (score 1):

Si lo estas poniendo así exactamente como lo pones acá:

```
<script src=" {% static 'lib/sweetalert2-9.10.0/sweetalert2.all.min.js' %} "></script>
```

Probablemente no te esta cargando el archivo js ya que tiene espacios en el src, tendria que ir así:

```
<script src="{% static 'lib/sweetalert2-9.10.0/sweetalert2.all.min.js' %}"></script>
```

Te recomiendo usar los DevTools de Chrome si usas este, o los que traen Firefox, Opera. Con estos es mas fácil saber que esta pasando, puedes ver si esta cargando el js o si te esta mandando algún error en la consola (sintaxis incorrecta, te falta un ; o algo mas).

Si estas en Chrome aprieta: Ctrl + Shift + i

Te aparecerán opciones: Elements, Console, Sources, Network. Sin cerrar estas opciones dale F5 a tu pagina, si no te carga algún archivo lo veras en el apartado Console y Network (Error 404), si es algun error de sintaxis lo veras en Console.

Comment: Gracias Kevin, pero así tengo los demás statics, de hecho pude solucionar el problema y ese no era el error que tenía.

Answer (score 0):

Yo tuve ese mismo problema, y lo que hice fue quitar las etiquetas html que tenia en el segundo for, en tu caso es la etiqueta html que usas dentro de ese for:

```
         {% for error in field.errors %}
            <li>
              errors += '{{error}}\n';
            </li>
         {% endfor %}
```

debe quedar de esta forma:

```
        {% for error in field.errors %}

            errors += '{{error}}\n';
        
        {% endfor %}
```

espero pueda ser de ayuda